# Abstract Syntax Tree: Object Chains (Class::StaticMethod().element.method())

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to make an abstract syntax tree for my programming language (closely like Java and C++)
and I was wondering what the best way would be to represent an object.

The following relations are possible:

Class::StaticObject

Class::StaticMethod()

object.attribute

object.method()

I was thinking about representing it this way (Pseudocode):

```
interface Primitive

Object : Primitive
{
    Lexeme Lefthandside; 
    boolean Staticreference; // true = ::, false is . operator
    Primitive Righthandside; // Can either be a method or an object, null if no operator is present
}

Method : Primitive
{
    Lexeme Lefthandside;
    List of Parameters; // Parameters of the method
}
```

Or would you guys go with another approach, I mean you could also use the operators . and :: as Node names and then attach two children to it, but wouldn't that make parsing and recursing the tree harder?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is usual to have a lexeme in the AST. They are used in the parse tree, but since the AST is created as part of the semantic analysis, you in fact have much richer information at that point. So instead the nodes in your AST should point to your symbol table.

For instance, the symbol table would contain an entry for the object (presumably inserted when you saw the declaration or the first use of the object), as well as an entry for the method (and the entry for the method contains a pointer to the entry for the class of the object.

At that point, you can decide whether the object is passed as an explicit parameter to the method (as in python or Ada for instance), or implicitly (C++).

So for object.method(), for instance, the AST would contain a node 'methodcall', with one child node 'self' pointing to the object entry, one child node 'method' pointing to the method entry, plus n children node for each of the parameters (pointing to the corresponding entries or to expression nodes).

Comment: Thank you for the response! (And sorry for my late response!) I think you're right: I was confused with a Parse Tree, but I still gained valuable information! I just have one more question: What would you think would be the best way to handle static scopings? Package::Class::Method. Also with some kind of symbol table?

Comment: Yes, I think the scoping is part of the symbol table. In fact, when you finished processing a scope, you might as well remove the local entities from the symbol table, to simplify the lookup later on.

Comment: My comment above was incorrect: you want to keep the variable in the symbol table since it is needed for code generation. The book Programming Language Pragmatics by M.L.Scott discusses the issue of scope at length, you will find it an interesting read

Comment: Thanks for coming back to tell me!:P That's really kind. I will definitly give it a look.